# Mapping virtual memory to virtual memory

Tags: c, winapi, posix

I am supplied with a struct that lies somewhere in the memory. Is it possible in WinAPI/POSIX to create a memory mapping that would alias the struct to a different part of the memory range so that identical bytes could be accessed from both locations? I cannot control the location of the original struct, but the new one can be stored anywhere.

I think, at least in WinAPI, I could create a temporary file and store the pages that contain the struct there, and then I could (hopefully) replace the original pages with new ones that point to the file, then map the file to a new section in the memory. However, I am worried about the performance of accessing the memory. Is there something better?

Comment: [I smell an XY problem here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); *you have "some" problem and you think that multimapping would solve it: __What is that problem exactly?__* Technically what you want to do is possible with some caveats. The problem is, that any form of single-memory-multiple-address mapping requires knowledge about this fact by all participating parties. Otherwise the code that created the original allocation which you intend to double map may free, reallocate or move the location, without the additional mapping being updated.

Comment: in kernel mode exist MDL - when you can get physical pages for memory location and then remap this (locked) pages at another (not paged system) address. in user mode no such functional. but your qestion unclear - what sense have 2 memory view to the same physical pages ?

Comment: @datenwolf I am well aware of the caveats and I can cope with them.

Comment: I don't see the point.  You need to know where the object you want to map to is in order to map it to another location.  And if you know where it is, you don't have to map to it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Specifically, I want to alias a part of the struct making it "global", and supply my own rest of the struct making that part "local". Then I call an external function which can be called on the original or new whole struct, but may modify the global (or local) part, but I don't know where and when, so making that part of memory shared would immediately make changes apparent in all "copies" of the struct. But it can also modify the local part where I don't want the changes to be mirrored.

Comment: @IllidanS4 - *making it "global", and supply my own rest of the struct making that part "local".*- unclear and imposssible

Comment: Memory mapping has to be page aligned )at least 4096 bytes) and in multiples of the allocation granularity (minimum of 65536 bytes), it is extremely unlikely that the shared/local portions of your struct span a page boundary. Guaranteeing such a thing while not impossible would be a huge pain. If you could guarentee that it would then be a matter of mapping the entire first page while caring only about the portion near the trail end.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you can use `memfd_create(2)` to allocate memory which you can access through a file descriptor. You'd then `write(2)` the original data to that in-memory file and map it over the original location with `mmap(2)` using `MAP_FIXED` flag, and then to another location with a non-fixed `mmap(2)`. Be aware that mapping must be a multiple of the underlying page size (4k in regular address space, or hugepage size if the memfd was allocated from hugepages).